woocommerce показывает цену товара только зарегистрированным пользователям
Нужно, чтобы цена товара показывалась всем, независимо от их статуса. Второй день туплю. На других сайтах такого никогда не случалось. Товар простой, цена есть, плагинов мало, тема вудмарт (лицензия).
Заранее спасибо, в Гугле вообще пустота, все перерыл ..



Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Вместо надписи "Войдите, чтобы увидеть цены" должна быть просто цена. Это карточка товара. Сейчас этот текст ведет на ссылку сайт/my-account для незарегистрированныз пользователей. Вукоммерс. Спасибо.

Проблема решена - она была в настройках темы. Извиняюсь за беспокойство
